# How to find out where variable is being set?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page and there is a public variable that is being set somewhere, but I can't find where it is being set. I have tried using 'Find Usages' but it only finds where it used within the same page.

Are there any other ways I can find out where it is being set?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET, C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Find All References should show you ALL uses in the solution, not only those within the page. If it shows only page uses, it's because there are no other uses.

Comment: @AlejoBrz - a field can be set using reflection, so it is possible that Find All References won't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it into property and set a breakpoint in setter.

Answer (score 4):

Make it private, then you'll see all the off-page references. You should never have a public member of a page.

Answer (score 2):

Comment the variable definition out. Rebuild, see where the errors are :)